# Completely Disable Fallbacks in SignalR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I have dug so many articles to figure out how to disable fallbacks in SignalR when the connection is lost but it seems like there are none.

My SignalR **Server Configurations** are the following

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
 GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(110);
 GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
 GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
.....
```

My client is using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` on Xamarin.Android as following

```
hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://*******azurewebsites.net/*****", querystringData);
mhubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("******");
try
{
 hubConnection.StateChanged += HubConnection_StateChanged; 
 await hubConnection.Start();
 return true;
}
catch (Exception X)
{
 Log.Info(TAG, "SignalR: " + X.Message);
 return false;
}
```

My whole setup works fine, just **one issue**. If the client's internet gets disconnected SignalR server does not trigger `OnDisconnected` straight away and starts the fallback. The whole process takes about 10 minutes before `OnDisconnected` is triggered.

So I can have two outcomes as following

> **OUTCOME 1: If the internet is turned back on**

In this case, when the client turns the internet back on, I try to re-connect the client, On the Server, SignalR closes the Old Connection and connects the client with the new ConnectionId :( makes me sad

> **OUTCOME 2: If the internet was never turned back on during that fallback window**

The SignalR server calls `OnDisconnected` :( Also makes me sad as it takes 10 minutes (from the time I disconnect the internet on client-side) as shown in the following timestamps

[image]

- 1 = Connetted
- 0 = Disconnected
- ConnectionIds to the right

**My question** is if SignalR is going to close the old connection with old `ConnectionId` and assign a new `ConnectionId` to the same client anyways then why the heck it is performing fallback and not triggering `OnDisconnected` on the first place. Plus and more importantly how to make sure it always triggers `OnDisconnected` and never goes to the fallback state?

Answer (score 1):

This is why the "new" `SignalR` for `.NET Core does` does not have a reconnect logic so the users are forced to implement it by themselves. I would check the connection on client side, and if it is doped, reconnect automatically. Also I would map users to groups so the connectionId in this case will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

ConnectionId should not be relied upon as your "userID". You should not care what the connectionId is for any user. Your client's userID (username) should be fixed and that is what you should be using upon connection or reconnect. If they opened multiple browser sessions you would have a different connectionID for each session, not much different than what you have today.

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)...

"You can create a group for each user, and then send a message to that group when you want to reach only that user. The name of each group is the name of the user. If a user has more than one connection, **each connection id** is added to the user's group."

It sounds like a review of this approach will resolve your issues.

OnDisconnect would be used for cleanup, such as removing the user from the group or some database job. This takes some time to occur because it is allowing your client time to reconnect before it occurs.

Hope that helps.